# Junk characters shows up when ssh to a server and execute tmux

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, tmux, iterm2

When I execute tmux on iTerm on MacOS, it works fine.
When I execute tmux on WSL on my Windows PC, it works fine.
However, when I ssh into my PC from my Macbook, execute WSL and execute tmux, weird characters show up.
[image]
I run Ubuntu2204 for WSL.
.tmux.conf on WSL has not been modified.
Can anyone tell me why this bug occured and how to resolve it?

Thanks alot

Comment: Is this Windows 10 or Windows 11?  I think I recall seeing the issue on one of my Win10 systems, but it's gone away since I upgraded to 11.  I'll have to see if I can reproduce on one of my older boxes.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds This is WSL on Windows 10